# Worldbuilding site performance

Tags: discussion

When viewing the main worldbuilding site in safari on an iMac there are performance issues.  Attempting to navigate pages, or simply scroll the page causes severe lag.

I do not experience this on any other stack exchange sites nor on the meta site.

Are there any special scripts being used on the main site? Are there any stats available on the performance of the site?

Comment: Hi Kami. The site uses the same basic framework as all other SE sites and to my knowledge there are no scripts running in relation to SE.

Comment: I think it's the robot on the left side.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Is scrolling on Anime and Wordbuilding slow as compared to sites with no background images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342517/352819)